# How do I find and edit cider-lein-parameters?

Tags: emacs, clojure, leiningen, spacemacs, cider

I'm new to Clojure, lein and spacemacs.  I'm attempting to get the `cider-jack-in` repl going in spacemacs, but it's failing to load.  After searching online, I think the solution to this issue is [here](https://github.com/clojure-emacs/cider/issues/1960).  Specifically,

"For anyone else running into this issue, this can be fixed by setting cider-lein-parameters to "repl :headless :host localhost" (the default value is "repl :headless :host ::")"

My problem is that I have no idea where the `cider-lein-parameters` file is, or if it even is a file.  And because I can't even locate it, I cannot edit it.  I've done extensive searches on this, but haven't found anything useful.  Can anyone guide me with a basic explanation of what this is and how I can edit it?  Is this a spacemacs thing?  Or a lein thing?

Any and all help would be greatly appreciated! Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Press M-x (Alt-x), then enter **set-variable** command
2. Select or enter **cider-lein-parameters** variable name
3. Enter its value in double quotes. e.g. "new value"

Comment: Thank you!  That definitely allowed me to find the elusive cider-lein-parameters, but it's still not fixing the issue for whatever reason. :/

Comment: What error message are you getting now? Try to set `debug-on-error` to `t` and reproduce the error (e.g. by running <kbd>M-x</kbd> `toggle-debug-on-error`)

Comment: thanks for the help!  i realized that what was going wrong went much deeper than simply accessing cider-lein-parameters, but it's since been figured out! i appreciate all the help! :)

Comment: @orangeorangepeel Could you please elaborate on what the actual issue was? I'm still facing the same issue when I create a new lein project and run cide-jack-in from emacs. I tried setting the cide-lein-parameters, too, but, to no luck.